# Can we use NetworkX package for finding subgraphs that are associated with a selected set of vertices?

Tags: networkx, subgraph

[the nodes in blue color are the selected set of vertices..we are trying to find out the subgraphs associated with these selected set of vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckH1A.jpg)

[expected frequent subgraph, where source vertex is one of the selected vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJMXt.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: You'll need to explain what is meant by "associated with".  Also, please follow the help center links above.

Comment: I think if you look at the images that I have given ,Its well explained what is the associated subgraphs.But still I would like to explain that  interesting subgraphs are not simply those that occur most frequently, but those that are most associated with a specific set of vertices. For example, in a biological graph, specific local subgraphs of interest might be those that can be associated with a disease.